# How do I specify a path for pyinstaller

Tags: widget, pyinstaller

I am learning in a tutorial, how to create widgets. The tutorial, however requires you to use pyinstaller to send the program to anyone. The problem I am facing is specifying my path.

Here is a recent attempt on the terminal command:

C:\tkinter.idea>cd pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=sun_icon.ico book.py
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment below if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The `cd` command only works for accessing directory files inside your system (folders). As pyinstaller.exe is a program you don't need to pass the `cd` command, remove this command and just input `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=sun_icon.ico book.py` in your cmd.

Comment: I've tried that but the new error message is pyinstaller.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: PyInstaller is a module, not an executable. Use `python -m PyInstaller --onefile --icon=whatever book.py` or `python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile --icon=whatever book.py`

Comment: Or add your `scripts` directory to `PATH` @Starbuck5.